Interpretting “Iudice me”
Looking at a medieval text, I have the line

Iudice me cignús et garrula cedat hirundo

Which I’m inclined to translate as “Judge me swan, even the swallow gives up talkative [things]” except that looking at Wiktionary, I don’t see any indication that “iudice” is a valid imperative form of “iudico” and it only shows a reference to the ablative of “iudex.” Any pointers on this?

For the sake of completeness, the source is the 'Carmen Philomelaicum' by Eugenius of Toledo, which appears as selection 153 in Beeson, A primer of Medieval Latin. The full sentence (lines 11–12) is:

Iudice me cignus et garrula cedat hirundo,
Cedat et illustri psittacus ore tibi.

Wiktionary is correct: iudice is the ablative of iudex. The phrase iudice me/me iudice is found also in Classical Latin and is an ablative absolute. Literally, it means 'with me as judge,' but it could be rendered more loosely as 'in my judgment' or 'in my estimation.'
Note that garrula isn't a neuter accusative plural substantive supplying the direct object of cedat but a feminine nominative singular modifying hirundo: 'the chattering swallow.'
The cedat in line 11 has both cignus (=cygnus) and hirundo as its subjects. (The use of a singular verb when the subject consists of 2 singular nouns joined by 'and' is quite common even in Classical Latin.) Note that cedat in both lines is present subjunctive. Here, it's being used, without a direct object, in the sense of 'to give way,' 'to yield first place,' 'to take second place,' or the like. Both occurrences of cedat use tibi in line 12 as their indirect object. I'd say that they're potential subjunctives. It may even be the case that the ablative absolute iudice me is meant to be conditional, so that each cedat represents a 'then' clause. In this case, the whole sentence means something like, 'If I were to judge, the swan and the chattering swallow would take second place to you, and so would the parrot with its clear-speaking mouth.'

And while we're at it, cedat is not indicative.

I wish I could give you an extra upvote for the extra comment. I’m guessing that cignús here is not a variant of cygnus, although I’m having a hard time figuring out what’s happening in that sentence with the singular

Ah, that helps. There is only subjunctive in the sentence (cedat reappears on the next line), but according to the introduction to Beeson’s Primer of Medieval Latin from which this passage comes, Medieval Latin does use the subjunctive in clauses of command (85a) so it might be, in my judgment, let the swan and garrulous swallow give way.

@D.A.Hosek, Knowing that this is in Beeson is helpful. I've thoroughly revised my answer after looking at the full passage.
